# How do test if a textbox is null using a list of textbox controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a list of the all the textboxes on a tab control in my winforms, c# application. Now what I would like to do is check each textbox in the list and test to see if that textbox is empty. If it is I would like to use the error provider to let the user know it needs to be filled. Here is the code I am using now.

```
//gathers the controls and adds them to a list on the main form
public static List<Control> GetControls(Control form, string type)
    {
        var controlList = new List<Control>();
        foreach (Control childControl in form.Controls)
        {
            if (childControl.Name.Contains(type))
            {
                controlList.Add(childControl);
            }
            if (childControl.HasChildren) GetControls(form, type);
        }
        return controlList;
    }


//Created in a class called DataVerification
public bool IsNotEmpty(string value, out string errorMessage)
    {
        errorMessage = "";
        if (value.Length == 0)
        {
            errorMessage = "This Field Is Required";
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }


//method that uses the DataVerification class and the error provider
 public void IsNotEmpty()
    {
        availableControls = GetControls(this.tabPage1, "Text");
        string errorMessage;
        DataVerification verify = new DataVerification();
        foreach (Control c in availableControls)
        {
            if (!verify.IsNotEmpty(c.Text, out errorMessage))
            {
                ErrorProvider.SetError(c, errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

Even if I could just display a messagebox that lets the user know which textboxes are empty would be fine. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The method `IsNotEmpty` is a boolean one; always return false.

```
public bool IsNotEmpty(string value, out string errorMessage)
{
    errorMessage = "";
    if (value.Length == 0)
    {
        errorMessage = "This Field Is Required";
        return true; //instead of false
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the control to a text-box in this manner:

```
            TextBox t = (TextBox)c;
```

and then use the t.Text to perform validation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what your question is...

What you can use to test if a textbox's value is empty is the
String.IsNullOrEmpty();

Instead of:

```
 if (!verify.IsNotEmpty(c.Text, out errorMessage))
            {
                ErrorProvider.SetError(c, errorMessage);
            }
```

Just do this:

```
 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text))
            {
                ErrorProvider.SetError(c, "This field is required!");
            }
```

Also, I recommend you change your naming scheme a tad. It's good practice to have methods and such be in the 'truthful' form. So instead of IsNotEmpty, IsEmpty would be easier to read/maintainable. That line of `!verify.IsNotEmpty()` throws a double negative!

EDIT:
As ahmad said: your method always returns false. It should read:

```
public bool IsNotEmpty(string value, out string errorMessage)
    {
        if (value.Length == 0)
        {
            errorMessage = "This Field Is Required";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you want to know where the `TextBox` controls are and verify *only* these, you can do the following:

```
foreach (Control c in availableControls)
{
    TextBox t = c as TextBox;
    if (t != null && !verify.IsNotEmpty(t.Text, out errorMessage))
        ErrorProvider.SetError(t, errorMessage);
}
```